# añadir filtros de búsqueda en un listado con paginación en php

Tags: php, jquery

```html
<?php

 header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
 include ('includes/conexion.php'); 
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilos.css">';


session_start();

echo'
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
     
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">USUARIOS
         <span class="caret"></span> </a>
          <ul  class="dropdown-menu">

         '; 

         if($_SESSION['rol_id'] == 1){

         echo '
           <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://disenopaginasweb.net/prueba_gema/usuarios/datosusuario.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
         ';
    }
   
   echo '
           <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://disenopaginasweb.net/prueba_gema/usuarios/pagina.php">Listado de Usuarios</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CLIENTES
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/clientes/datoscliente.php">Nuevo Cliente</a></li>
            <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/clientes/paginaclientes.php">Listado de Clientes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">WEBS
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/webs/nuevaweb.php">Nueva Web</a></li>
             <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/webs/paginawebs.php">Listado de Webs</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>



       <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CLIENTES BAJA
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/clientes/prueba.php">Prueba</a></li>
           <li><a  class="dropdown-item" href="http://prueba_gema/clientes/listado_clientes.php">Listado</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       


     </ul>
 </div>
 </nav> 

'; 

?>
```

Tengo un `php` que muestra un listado con paginación (hasta aquí funciona) y quiero añadirle un filtro. La cuestión sería que entre todos mis clientes (que es lo que lista) pueda elegir entre los que están activos o los que están de baja (un simple valor de la tabla en `bd`).

El problema es que al añadirlo, si yo le doy al botón para que haga el filtrado, lo hace, pero si le doy a cualquiera de los botones de paginación no funciona; es como si cambiara el valor del filtro y además no muestra nada.

En el listado de los clientes, al lado de cada uno, aparece un botón de mostrar que lleva al detalle de cada cliente.

Adjunto código, yo creo que es algún problema con hacerlo en dos formularios y el orden pero estoy perdida.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listado Clientes Baja</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript">
  function seleccionar(valor) {
   
    let id = document.getElementById("id");
  
    id.value = valor;
  }
</script>


<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
  include ('../includes/conexion.php');
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilos.css">';
?>

</head>
<body>

  <?php

  include '../cabecera.php';

  include '../menu.php';

  echo '<section class="contenedor-principal">';

  ?>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel-body">


  <?php

  // filtro para mostrar clientes
  echo '
  <form name="formulario" method="post">
    <select name="mostrar" id="mostrar">
      <option value=""> selecciona tipo de clientes </option>
      <option value="0" > Activos </option>
      <option value="1"> Baja </option>
    </select>

    <input name="formulario" type="submit" value="Mostrar">
  </form>
  ';


  // $buscar = $_POST['buscador'];

  $buscar = "";
  echo "</br>";
  $clientes_mostrar =  $_POST['mostrar'];
  if($clientes_mostrar == "0"){echo "LISTADO DE CLIENTES ACTIVOS"."</br>";}
  else{echo "LISTADO DE CLIENTES DADOS DE BAJA"."</br>";}


  echo '<form name="id" action="mostrarcliente.php"  method="post">';

  $registro_por_pagina = 10;
  $pagina = '';
  if(isset($_GET["pagina"]))
  {
   $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
  }
  else
  {
   $pagina = 1;
  }

  $start_from = ($pagina-1)*$registro_por_pagina;

  // echo "Nº página: ".$pagina." --- comienzo: ".$start_from."</br>";
  // si no hay busqueda
  if(empty($buscar)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE borrado=$clientes_mostrar order by id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $registro_por_pagina";
  }
  else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE borrado=$clientes_mostrar AND (nombre LIKE '%" .$buscar. "%' OR apellidos LIKE '%" .$buscar. "%') order by id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $registro_por_pagina";
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);

  ?>

  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
       </tr>

    <?php

     if ($result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query)){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {

       ?>
       <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["apellidos"]; ?></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Mostrar"
          onclick="seleccionar(<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row["id"])) ?>)" />
            </td>
       </tr>
       <?php
       }
      }
       ?>
      </table>


   <div align="center">
      <br />
      <?php
      $page_query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE borrado=$clientes_mostrar ORDER BY id DESC";
      $page_result = mysqli_query($enlace, $page_query);
      $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);
      $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$registro_por_pagina);
      $start_loop = $pagina;
      $end_loop = $total_pages;
      $diferencia = $total_pages - $pagina;

      // echo "records: ".$total_records." pages: ". $total_pages." start: ".$start_loop." end:".$end_loop." diferencia: ".$diferencia."</br>";

      if($diferencia > 10)
      {
        $start_loop = $total_pages - 10;

        $end_loop = $start_loop + 9;
      }
      if($pagina > 1)
      {
       echo "<a class='pagina' href='clientes_baja.php?pagina=1'>Primera</a>";
       echo "<a class='pagina' href='clientes_baja.php?pagina=".($pagina - 1)."'><<</a>";
      }
      for($i=1; $i<=$end_loop; $i++)
      {     
       echo "<a class='pagina' href='clientes_baja.php?pagina=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
      }
      if($pagina < $end_loop)
      {
       echo "<a class='pagina' href='clientes_baja.php?pagina=".($pagina+1)."'>>></a>";
       echo "<a class='pagina' href='clientes_baja.php?pagina=".$total_pages."'>Última</a>";
      }


      ?>
      </div>
      <br /><br />

   </div>

  <?php
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />';
      echo '</form>';


  echo "<br/>"."<br/>"."<br/>";


  ?>



  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <?php 
  echo '<a href="../principal.php">Volver al Indice</a> <br/>';
    include '../pie.php';
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedo observar que estás usando `Bootstrap`.

`DataTables` de `Bootstrap` puede ayudarte con el filtrado, búsqueda y paginación. Mira un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

**Fuente:** [Bootstrap DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

Sólo debes cambiar el contenido de los `th` y los `td` para que muestre la información de tu base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Haciendo lo que me dices, tan sólo muestra una tabla normal, sin filtros y en consola me da un error: "TypeError: c is undefined   jquery.dataTables.min.js:90:257". ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Debes agregar todas las dependencias que te pongo en el ejemplo, tanto los `link` entre las etiquetas `<head></head>` de tu proyecto y los `script` antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`. Estos últimos _(los `script`)_ es mejor ubicarlos al final de toda la estructura `HTML` y no en el `<head>`. Si aún sigues con problemas, me comentas para que miremos que otra cosa puede estar pasando.

Comment: OK. Así funciona perfecto pero no entiendo porqué me ha dejado de funcionar el menú que tenía antes. Le llamo con un include. Añado a la pregunta inicial el código aunque me temo que debe ser algún problema con boostrap  porque en los archivos que no tengo la paginación funciona correctamente. ¿Es eso posible?. Muchas gracias

Comment: Probablemente estés linkeando nuevamente las dependencias de `Bootstrap` en los archivos `cabecera.php` y `menu.php`. De ser así, evita hacerlo ya que estarías sobre escribiendo los estilos personalizados que tengas en `menu.php`, por ejemplo. Haz un respaldo de tus archivos, elimina las dependencias de los archivos  `cabecera.php` y `menu.php`, al hacer el `include`, deberían tomar los estilos de la pagina actual.

Comment: Como esta respuesta solucionó tu necesidad, te recomiendo marcarla como útil y aceptarla, de esta manera ambos ganamos reputación y servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Perdona por mi tardanza. Efectivamente el error era volver a hacer link a boostrap. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha sido muy útil.

Comment: Es con todo el gusto. Me alegra que te haya sido útil!

Comment: Es con todo el gusto. Me alegra que te haya sido útil!